Plotting results diagrams in a curve line, how can i do this in Python?
I need to plot post-processed results extracted from a tunnel lining plate in PLAXIS 2D.
Do you have any ideas on how to present these results in Python/Matplotlib similarly to how they are displayed in PLAXIS? Please refer to the image below.
The geometry of the tunnel lining is defined by X and Y coordinates. The third value (represented in the red diagram) corresponds to the results for the tunnel lining, such as displacements, forces, etc.

EDIT: After some digging, I found an example from the paper that represents more or less what I want to replicate.
I understood this is done with polar projection and found this question that partially answers my question.
Antenna pattern polar plot
However, I am still trying to figure out how to change the geometry from a circle to a non-circle geometry ( to replicate the examples from the paper ) Any ideas how can i do that?


Which paper? Have you considered reaching out to the authors?

No, I cannot find their contacts. I want to understand how this can be implemented in Python.

What paper is it from?
